# Unable to get image after reinstalling the app

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I am not able to get the images stored in Parse-Server as a file, once I reinstall the app. It works fine while a user is logged in but once the app is uninstalled only files are unable to access.It shows exception saying :- File doesn't exist . And I am not able to download image in parse server as well .It will redirect me to role section.

Tried changing version of parse in gradle.

I should be able to access images after reinstalling app. And I should be able to download image in parse.

code written to upload image-----------------------

```
ParseFile filename = new ParseFile("name.png", Byte);  
filename.saveInBackground();  
classObject.put("imagePic", filename);  
classObject.saveInBackground();
```

Retrieving from Parse server--------------

```
file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {  
    @Override  
    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {  
        if(e == null) {  
            if(data != null) {  
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);  
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you share some code of how you are storing and retrieving these files? Can you also share some url of a file that is not available?

Comment: Yes I did . Please check edited question

Comment: Do you see any error message? Can you share the url of an image that you cannot download?

Comment: Error----
I/Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Comment: Image URL
http://"serverAddress I removed it for security reson"/undefined/files/e67bb26b9bc2fc3173d5d0a6d66ccc320ca0da0a/154a460da3bddd2052a4871e10e70a5c_Hwllo.png

Comment: Can you please let me know whats the error @DaviMacêdo

Comment: i shared both error message and image url .please look into it. @DaviMacêdo

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It looks like something related to the undefined in your url. Can you share how you are initializing Parse Server and in special your file adapter and public server url?